# Selecting rows fails when code is run together, works when run individually

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to read two excel tables into R, delete the first 4 rows and then make the top row the column names:

```
Corrugator <- read_excel(data_files[2], sheet = "EMG_Corrugator")
Corrugator <- Corrugator[4:nrow(Corrugator),]
Corrugator <- Corrugator %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

This worked fine for the second excel table. I kept getting an error for the fist table however, where I just say `[[1]]` instead:
`Warning: Row 1 does not provide unique names. Consider running clean_names() after row_to_names().`

After some testing I noticed that whenever I run the code altogether, it seems to delete the top 6 rows and not just the top 4, resulting in the aforementioned error due to multiple columns having the same name. However, if I run the lines one by one, waiting until the last has finished, I do not get the error and everything works as intended! Curiously, the first excel table reads fine even when the code is executed together.

Since I am planning to use this code in a for loop, running the lines one by one is not a possibility. I would be thankful for any leads!

Comment: This is probably dependent on the data, but right now, it look like you read the excl file, which would have column names and then four rows of data you need to delete, then make the sixth row your column names (4 rows + one column name row to be removed). With read_excel, you can ```skip``` rows. Does it help at all to just skip the first 5 rows?  (I was thinking 5 because it would skip the column names of the excel sheet, then the first four rows).

Comment: Using `skip = 4` worked nicely, the first 4 rows were skipped and the 5th was made into the new column names, as I wanted it. Thank you!